# My question disappeared so can I see the actual reason somewhere?

Tags: support

I am pretty sure I asked a question 'few' days ago on SF and also got one down vote.

So I searched a bit and had a glance on: https://serverfault.com/help/roomba

I really cannot remember anymore if the question was older than 30 days - which might be the case - so is there any possibility to see anywhere if that was the case and maybe the original question also?

Comment: Note that you can also [see your recently (less than 60 days) deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/241919)

Comment: Now that you told me I found it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By (faulty?) design the UI hides deleted posts even from their author unless you have sufficient reputation...

https://serverfault.com/q/924399/

> deleted by Community♦ 54 mins ago (RemoveDeadQuestions)
>
> This question was automatically deleted. Please see the help center for more information.

Comment: Ok, the reputation... Thanks :) And yes, I can see the date over 30 days ago.

Comment: It's by design that only 10k+ reps are able to see deleted posts on the list, but OP should be able to see it on [deleted recent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492) though.